# EFA SPSS and Cronbach's Alpha

Tags: regression, correlation, factor-analysis, reliability, confirmatory-factor

I have done the EFA in SPSS for my questionnaires and found 4 factors. Now should I use this EFA result to compute the Cronbach's Alpha, and if so then how to do that? Or Cronbach's Alpha is done separately without bothering the EFA?

Comment: What's the precise question here? If it is about how to do something in SPSS, then it would be off-topic here. If it's about alpha, then what you are asking should be made clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Cronbach's alpha is a measure of inter-item reliability.

Factor analysis is a method of finding latent variables that are linear combinations of observed variables.

You can use alpha to test the inter-item reliability of the variables that make up each factor you discover.